# What's wrong with my password program?

Tags: java, passwords

Helllo can somebody tell my why it doesn't tell my that the password is invalid, when I don't write the valid password?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {  
    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the password:");
        in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String pass;
        pass = in.nextLine();
        if(pass.length() < 4){
            System.out.println("The password is too short");

        } else if(pass.length() > 9){
            System.out.println("The password is too long");

        }

        if(pass.equalsIgnoreCase("hudhud")){
            System.out.println("Welcome BOSS");
            while (!pass.equals("hudhud")){
                System.out.println("The password is invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you randomly switch to `while`? You also nested it inside a condition that pre-guarantees it won't hit.

Comment: Do I've to write if else instead of while?

Comment: I want it to write `The password is invalid`, when the user doesn't write "hudhud"

Comment: Celeo: Nothing has changed. It doesn't say `The password is invalid`when the password is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test cases:

```
Input: foo
Output: The password is too short

Input: foobar
Output: 

Input: foobarfoobar
Output: The password is too long

Input: hudhud
Output: Welcome BOSS
```

Your while statement

```
while (!pass.equals("hudhud")){
    System.out.println("The password is invalid");
}
```

is dead code - it cannot be reached. You check if `pass` equals `hudhud`. Inside that check, you have a `while` loop without a break statement testing if the password doesn't equal `hudhud`. At this point, it cannot equal anything other than `hudhud`.

Note that nothing is printed to the screen when the password is between 4 and 9 characters and not equal to `hudhud`. If you're trying to change that, add an `else` to the `if(pass.equalsIgnoreCase("hudhud"))` check.

Comment: I am not seeing any syntax errors when I compile and run that.

Comment: You're getting close, though - just add a trailing `else` to catch any password that doesn't trigger any of the other conditions.

Comment: I just added `} else if (!pass.equals("hudhud")){`